# Read a list of CSV files in Talend with ; in field

Tags: csv, talend

I have a list of CSV files which i receive for ETL into database every month. Its in a folder. My data has `;` in many columns as well. For example, in the location column values like `New York; USA` are present, which i want to appear in a single column instead of splitting into many columns. How do i specify delimiter then?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot have the field separator included in the field content or you have to incluse these values between "". For example:
`blabla;"New York; USA";blabla`
Other solution, change the field delimitor to a more specific (and unused) character.

I'm afraid there is no better solution.

Regards,
TRF

Comment: What can be alternative or better solution for this issue? I do not want to loose on data. Thanks!

Comment: Better solution would be that the sending party doesn't use the same separator as for data.

Answer (score 1):

As TRF mentioned, you can't have the delimiter as part of the non-delimiting text in your file.

My workaround for that would be the following:

1) Read the file with a `tFileInputFullRow` (https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tFileInputFullRow)

2) Use a `tReplace` to replace the `;` with some other character,
    say `-`, for the problem cells (in your case, replace `"New York;USA"` with `"New York-USA"`. You can also use the regex option in the `tReplace` component to make it a generic rule.

3) Save that output into another file

4) Now read the new file using `;` as the delimiter

References:

1) `tReplace`: https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/18.16+tReplace

2) Regex: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: For the second step suggested, i tried using `tReplace` for all columns, however when i export it through tOutputdelimited component, i see that it has not been removed the `;` sign. Anything that i am missing?

Comment: Is the `whole word` checkbox unchecked? (in the `tReplace` component)

Comment: I added more details to item 4. See if it helps now.

Comment: yes, it is unchecked. I still have the issue, is it because tFileInputFullRow component considers everything in lines and not in columns, despite defining schema? As an experiemnt, i created a file with only one column and tried doing it and it worked. However when i include teh original file with many columns and clean multiple such columns after defining schema, it does not work.

Comment: I am stuck at step 2 _Use a tReplace to replace the ;_ as it is not replacing anything. Refer my 2nd comment above.

Comment: Did you try replacing `"New York;USA"` with `"New York-USA"` **only** ? If you keep the generic replace of `;` with `-` it will never work.

Comment: I tried doing that through tReplace as you suggested, however it is simply not working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142199/discussion-between-maira-bay-and-enthusiast).