# tReplace not removing comma in Talend workflow

Tags: talend

I have a workflow which i am using to remove comma sign `,` from the data. However its is not working.

[image]

Edit: I am adding new screenshots

[image]

tMap properties

[image]

sample data

```
id
Shenzhen City, Guangdong, China
Rest of Hunan, China
China
Wuxi City, Jiangsu, China
Jinshan District, Shanghai, China
JingÕan District, Shanghai, China
Yangpu District, Shanghai, China
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **disabling checkbox** **`"Whole word"`**. If then not working as expected, follow below approach.

Instead of using `treplace` component, use the code like below in `tMap` component

`row1.id.replaceAll(",","-");`

The above will give you the expected result

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: First suggestion does not seem to work, as it splits output into multiple rows. For the tMap solution, where can i use the formula? I mean which field? I am new to Talend

Comment: @Enthusiast In that case, first try googling about `tMap` component. [Good to start here](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8123244)

Comment: I tried, but to no avail. It still has the comma in values

Comment: @Enthusiast Can you provide the screenshot of modified job design and tmap properties?

Comment: Done!! I have added new screenshots

Comment: Also can you please provide some sample data from your source file?

Comment: I have added that too!!

Comment: The other explanation I can think of is that your file has a different encoding than the one you are reading. For example, if your file is encoded with windows and you are reading it as UTF-8.

Comment: I clarified my answer to your other (related) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470131/read-a-list-of-csv-files-in-talend-with-in-field I think it will help you